# Friend function not working

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following code I am trying to have a friend function access the private member of the class.  To my understanding I am correctly declaring it as a friend function, but VS2012 is giving me the error:

```
error C2248: 'X::S::s_' : cannot access private member declared in class 'X::S'
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?  This is the simplest example that demonstrates the compiler error that I could come up with.

```
namespace X
{
    class S
    {
        friend std::string r(X::S &s);
        std::unique_ptr<std::istream> s_;
    };
}
std::string r(X::S &s)
{
    auto& x = s.s_;
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're defining `::r`, not `X::r`, which is what your friend declaration is for. Move the function into the namespace alongside the class, or define it right inside the class, though that can be problematic with a class template or keeping the class definition concise. If the definition is in a separate file, you can still enclose it with the namespace like you do the class to add it to the namespace. I would also suggest removing the `X::` qualification as it's already in `X`.

```
namespace X
{
    class S
    {
        friend std::string r(S &s);
        std::unique_ptr<std::istream> s_;
    };

    std::string r(S &s)
    {
        auto& x = s.s_;
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I declare the global function friend instead of moving the function into the namespace?  If I do friend std::string ::r(S&s); it says that std::string doesn't have a member 'r'.

Comment: @Graznarak, Apart from moving the class out of the namespace, I'm not sure if you can.

Comment: @Graznarak: Try `friend std::string (::r)(S& s);`  But you'll need a forward declaration.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Very interesting :) It's funny, though, because you need everything in a specific order: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3e644580efd9de30d72af54ef75f40fc-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f

Answer (score 6):

If you want a global `r`:

```
namespace X
{
    class S;
}

std::string r(X::S &s);

namespace X
{
    class S
    {
        friend std::string (::r)(X::S &s);
        std::unique_ptr<std::istream> s_;
    };
}

std::string r(X::S &s)
{
    auto& x = s.s_;
    return "";
}
```

- demo: http://ideone.com/EyQAL7

Comment: On my system, the extra parentheses around `::r` alone was sufficient. I didn't nee the forward declaration of `class X::S`.